# Insert Error:Directory lookup for the file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am have a register page on my website built in VS2010 and when I fill the form in a click register I am getting the following error. Help would be appreciated.

```
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
      Message=Insert Error:Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\myname\Documents\myname\Project\App_Data\SJDatabase.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(error not found).
    Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\myname\Project\App_Data\SJDatabase.mdf' as database 'SJDatabase'.
```

connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

    <add name="MyConsString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|SJDatabase.mdf;
                             Initial Catalog=SJDatabase;
                             Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: are you sure the path `C:\Users\myname\Documents\myname\\Project\App_Data` exists?

Comment: can you post some of your code. Connection string mainly

Comment: @w0lf yes it does exist, typed it incorrectly, please view updated version.

Comment: @Diego connection string added, please see above

Comment: don't know if this causes any problems, but your second connection string has `Integrated Security=SSPI;` twice. You probably need `User Instance=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a backslash on `|DataDirectory|\SJDatabase.mdf`

also, you have Integrated Security=SSPI twice and I dont think you need the AttachDBFileName part

try something more simple like this:

```
"data source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=SJDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: this works now but I am getting a new error: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects.
Parameter name: value